# choosing a good mongodb sharding key

Tags: mongodb, sharding

I have a collection with 3 fields

- _id = ID_account mixed with ID_reccord = int64
- id_account = int32 (autoincrement key)
- id_reccord = int32 (autoincrement key)

in the collection, 1 id_account have an average on 300 records, but very few id_account (special account) can have millions reccords.

initialy i want to use the ID_account as the shard key, but it's sean it's will be not very good for the few accounts who have millions records

now i think to use the ID_account and id_reccord as the shard key. but as the id_reccord is an autoincremented key, is it not a problem ? is it not better to use instead a random key that i can extract from the ID (like the inverted_id or something else you can suggest me to genereate a random number from the id)?

so what the better choice :

- _id = 13846974562326
- id_account=3224
- id_reccord=22
- inverted_id=62326547964831

and

- _id = 13846974562327
- id_account=3224
- id_reccord=23
- inverted_id=72326547964831

and

- _id = 13846974562328
- id_account=3224
- id_reccord=24
- inverted_id=82326547964831

then what is better

1. use shard key on id_account
2. use shard key on id_account and id_reccord
3. use shard key on id_account and inverted_id

all id_account, id_reccord, and inverted_id can be extracted from the _id

thanks by advance for your help

Comment: How are you querying the data? That's a critical question. From the information here I'd suggest using a [hashed key](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/shard-collection-with-a-hashed-shard-key/) on the `_id`.

Comment: i query the data like where id = 13846974562328 and id_account=3224 (for exemple) and like where id_account=3224 ... because of the last query, using the id for the shard key is not efficient at all :(